# How to remember visited links when links are dynamic?

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts, struts-1

We are using struts in our application. On one of the jsp pages, we display a table with the list of items retrieved from the database. Inside the table, we have a column with hyperlinks, to view the additional details about the specific line item.

Now a new requirement from the customer is that webpage should remember the links visited by the user. However, unlike the static links, in our case these are dynamic links, generated every time upon loading of that page. Due to this, the links always appear as fresh/unread, even if user may have already viewed the details about the item.

Need advice on how to achieve the above requirement.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is; presumably you can keep track of what items a user has visited with little difficulty, and you'd style the dynamic links via CSS like normal. What's the actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on your implementation type. Assuming, it is an authenticated page then you can probably have database table that will keep track of the links visited by this user and on page load you can use this table data to highlight the links as visited or not visited.